# How to configure a Route resource with root

Tags: routes, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.1, and creating a route resource like: `Route::resource('/page', 'PagesController');`. But I don't want `/page` to be my resource, or `/page/about`. I'd rather have `/about` etc.

When I use `Route::resource('/', 'PagesController');` however, my names and URIs are ruined. To restore the names I've used:

```
Route::resource('/page', 'PagesController', [
    'names' => [
        'index' => 'pages.index',
        'show' => 'pages.show',
        'create' => 'pages.create',
        'store' => 'pages.store',
        'edit' => 'pages.edit',
        'update' => 'pages.update',
        'destroy' => 'pages.destroy'
    ]
]);
```

This makes `/` take me to the index file, but `/about` and the like do not work, because the URI (which shows as `{}`) does not have any parameters.

I can manually set up all my routes with `$router->get('/', 'PagesController@index");` and the like, but having one of those for everything seems like the wrong way to do this.

How would I set up a route resource to be used at the root with parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've faced the same issues with you, but I can't find any solutions out there.

Take a look on **register** function in **laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ResourceRegistrar.php**, we can see that $base is null in this case:

```
// We need to extract the base resource from the resource name. Nested resources
// are supported in the framework, but we need to know what name to use for a
// place-holder on the route wildcards, which should be the base resources.
$base = $this->getResourceWildcard(last(explode('.', $name)));

$defaults = $this->resourceDefaults;

foreach ($this->getResourceMethods($defaults, $options) as $m) {
    $this->{'addResource'.ucfirst($m)}($name, $base, $controller, $options);
}
```

This makes adding methods go wrong:

```
 * Add the show method for a resourceful route.
 *
 * @param  string  $name
 * @param  string  $base
 * @param  string  $controller
 * @param  array   $options
 * @return \Illuminate\Routing\Route
 */
protected function addResourceShow($name, $base, $controller, $options)
{
    $uri = $this->getResourceUri($name).'/{'.$base.'}';

    $action = $this->getResourceAction($name, $controller, 'show', $options);

    return $this->router->get($uri, $action);
}
```

I'm not sure that if we can do anything more than manually add each methods, but that what I've done in my case.